# Laravel: error while trying to upload multiple files

Tags: laravel

I am trying to upload multiple images but unfortunately, I am getting an error  **"message": "The file "phpzP428U.png" does not exist",** How can I solve this? Thanks.

**return request**

```
dd($request->all())
```

[image]

**InboxController**

```
  foreach ($request["file"] as $key => $value) {
      $file = Storage::disk('yourstitchart')->putFile('', $value);
      array_push($files, $file);
    }

    foreach ($request["users"] as  $key => $users) {
      $digitzingInbox = new Inbox;
      $digitzingInbox->file = json_encode($request[$files]);
      $digitzingInbox->order_id = $request->order_id;
      $digitzingInbox->order_name = $request->order_name;
      $digitzingInbox->width = $request->width;
      $digitzingInbox->height = $request->height;
      $digitzingInbox->placement = $request->placement;
      $digitzingInbox->format = $request->format;
      $digitzingInbox->fabric = $request->fabric;
      $digitzingInbox->instruction = $request->instruction;
      $digitzingInbox->to_user = $users;
      $digitzingInbox->from_user = Auth::user()->id;
      $digitzingInbox->type = 2;
      $digitzingInbox->save();
    }
```

Comment: did u set the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form ?

Answer (score -1):

I think its self explanatory, that file may not exist in folder. Look it up the name if it matches.